# How do I optimize my MongoDB Database?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, optimization, database

## The problem:

I have two collections in my database:

```
// UnifiedPost
public class UnifiedPost
{
    public UnifiedPost() { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public int OriginalId { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    [AlsoNotifyFor("IsVideo")]
    public string FullSized { get; set; }
    public char Rating { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string Dimensions { get { return string.Format("{0}x{1}", Width, Height); } }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonIgnore]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectId> TagIds { get; set; }
    public char Site { get; set; }

    public bool IsVideo { get { return FullSized.Contains(".mp4") || FullSized.Contains(".webm"); } }

    public string UniversalId { get; set; } // UNIQUE index (Site + Original id; fe. S3001)
}

// Tag
public class Tag
{
    public Tag() { }

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There's around 4 million entries in the `Posts` collection as of now. Queries such as `db.Posts.find()`, `db.Posts.find( { "_id": ObjectId(xyz) } )` and `db.Posts.find( { "UniversalId": "S3001" } )` are returning results in a matter of ms.

On the other hand, queries like `.find( { "Site": "S" } ) or`.find( { "OriginalId": {$lt: "25" } })` can take even 30s to complete.

## What I already have:

I'm using an extension method to add/update a unique key to the `UniversalId` property:

```
if (!createIndex)
{
    await postsColl.Indexes.AddOrUpdateAsync(new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true }, new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<UnifiedPost>().Ascending(o => o.UniversalId));
    createIndex = true;
}
```

## What I'm unsure of:

- I don't know if I should use indexes for any other fields, and what types of indexes I should use, for that matter.
- `Site` holds a `char` value and there are ~6 possibilities in the collection as of now. It might or might not increase further. 
  *`OriginalId` is just an `int` that represents the post on the original site. This id isn't unique, as there is roughly as many `1`s, `2`s, `3`s (and so on) as there are different Sites in the collection.

What would be the best way to optimize the database so I can query posts based on these properties with a reasonable operation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to optimize the database so I can query posts based on these properties with a reasonable operation time?

Add indexes on those fields, of course.

Comment: Something like this? `postsColl.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<UnifiedPost>.Ascending(o => o.Site));`

Comment: @Reynevan: i have no idea about c# code for this :)

Comment: Alright, I added these 3 indexes and now inserting the data is extremely, unimaginably slow. Probably did something wrong

Comment: @Reynevan: that's what indexes do. They speed up the queries and slow down the writes. Although if it's now "unimaginably slow", then yes, maybe you did something wrong. Or define "unimaginably slow" (how long in milliseconds, what write throughput you had before and after, etc.)

Comment: ~800 UnifiedPosts entries in about 30s. Currently I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: @Reynevan: yes, it shouldn't be _that_ slow, even on the most ancient hardware.

Comment: Alright, seems like restarting the server fixed it :) Thanks, it works much better now! Edit: Still slower than before but I can live with that. Compared to 30s delay that's perfect